# Uncaught ReferenceError: .parent() or closest()

Tags: jquery

Within a loop, multiple divs like the one below appears.

```
<div id="author-id-3" class="follow-me">                         
    <div class="author-follow">
    <a id="3" class="meta-badge"><span class="icon-close"></span> Follow</a>
    </div>          
</div>
```

I use ajax to update the data within a db.

```
jQuery('.author-follow').on('click', '.meta-badge', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();                     

    var user_id         = $('.author-follow a.meta-badge').attr('id');  

    $.ajax( {
        ...                     
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.follow-me .author-follow').fadeOut( 'fast' );
            $( '<div class="icon-loading"></div>' ).hide().appendTo('.follow-me').fadeIn( 'slow' );

        },
        success: function( data ) {
            $('.follow-me .icon-loading').remove();
            $('.follow-me').html( ajax_setting.ajax_follow_success ).hide().fadeIn( 'slow' );
             console.log( user_id );
        }

    } ) 

});
```

This causes that all `follow-me` divs get's updated with the `ajax_follow_success` function when any particular button is clicked on a page. While it should only appear within that specific button area.

I tried using:

```
$toggle = $(this).parent().parent().find('follow-me');

beforeSend: function() {
    $toggle.fadeOut( 'fast' );
    $( '<div class="icon-loading"></div>' ).hide().appendTo($toggle).fadeIn( 'slow' );  
},
```

But then I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: $toggle is not defined`

I even tried it with `closest()` but it doesn't quite work as well (most likely because I don't use it properly).

```
beforeSend: function() {
    $(this).closest('.author-follow').fadeOut( 'fast' );    
    $( '<div class="icon-loading"></div>' ).hide().appendTo( $(this).closest('.follow-me') ).fadeIn( 'slow' );  
},
```

Any help in putting me on the right track is much appreciated.

**Edit:**

I also approached it from a slightly different angle (without success).

```
var div_id          = $('.follow-me').attr('id');

beforeSend: function() {                
$('#' + div_id + ' .author-follow').fadeOut( 'fast' );                      
$( '<div class="icon-loading"></div>' ).hide().appendTo('#' + div_id + '').fadeIn( 'slow' );
console.log( div_id  );                         
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `.` character in the class `.find('follow-me')` which means it is searching for the tag `follow-me` not the class.

```
$toggle = $(this).parent().parent().find('.follow-me');
//                                        ^ use '.follow-me'
```

Comment: Even with the `dot` added, it still doesn't quite work as I hope it would.